# How to use Amazon.NoIntent if I have to handle multiple 'No' utterances

Tags: python, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I have a conversation like:

```
Alexa: Do you want to go to a movie?
User: No
Alexa : Can I help you with anything else?
User: No
Alexa: Okay, until next time.
```

Something like this:

```
if intent_name == "AMAZON.NoIntent":
        return no_response(session_attributes)


def no_response(session_attributes):
    if session_attributes is None:
        card_title = "NO RESPONSE"
        speech_output = "Okay. Do you want me to help with anything else?"
        reprompt_text = "Sorry. Can you repeat that again, please?"
        should_end_session = False
        session_attributes['myorder']='first'
    else:
        card_title = "NO RESPONSES"
        speech_output = "Thankyou."
        reprompt_text = "Sorry. Can you repeat that again, please?"
        should_end_session = True

    return build_response(session_attributes, build_speechlet_response(
    card_title, speech_output, reprompt_text, should_end_session))
```

How to enable alexa to provide different responses for different No ??

Answer (score 0):

you have to use alexa session attribute state and based on the state make decision tree on how to handle it

Comment: any example on how to implement it or where can I learn more about this session attribute?

Comment: i am not sure of python but in node js you can have a look https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs.
The concept remain the same you add an attribute in session node for to identify from where you are coming

Comment: like in your example case when your skill is responding to go for a movie create a session say 'movieprompted'  then when user responds no then in Amazon.No intent handler  check for the session attribute if it's a 'movieprompted' then respond with anythingelse and clear the movieprompted session attribute

Comment: thanks for the info. any python code to have a reference would be great.

Comment: check my edits on the code. could you help me out @user398707

Comment: Please have a  look https://medium.com/ai2-blog/alexafsm-a-finite-state-machine-python-library-for-building-complex-alexa-skills-61c3af5a299d